# How do I use frisby.js with SSL client certificates?

Tags: ssl, frisby.js

I have a question about the use of Frisby.js with a REST service that uses SSL client certificates.

If I use the Request package to talk to the service, I can do something like this:

```
request.get(URL, {
  agentOptions: {
    // Or use `pfx` property replacing `cert` and `key` when using private key, certificate and CA certs in PFX or PKCS12 format:
    pfx: fs.readFileSync(pfxFilePath),
    passphrase: 'password',
    ca: fs.readFileSync(caFilePath)
  }
});
```

Since Frisby uses request, I assume I can do something similar in a Frisby test, but I can’t seem to get the syntax correct.

Can you suggest something that might work? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The `.get()` and `.post()` methods can take an additional struct with contents similar to the options parameter of [`https.request()`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback). You will need to supply values for (some of): `pfx`, `key`, `cert`, `ca` and `passphrase`.

Something like this:

```
var fs     = require('fs');
var frisby = require('frisby');

frisbee.create( 'Test name' )
  .get(
    'https://localhost/rest/endpoint',
    {
      key:        fs.readFileSync( "/path/to/certificates/certificate.key" ),
      cert:       fs.readFileSync( "/path/to/certificates/certificate.crt" ),
      ca:         fs.readFileSync( "/path/to/certificates/ca.crt" ),
      passphrase: "your pass phrase"
    }
  )
  .expectStatus( 200 )
  .toss();
```

Comment: great, it worked! how do I do it for every request (in frisby.globalSetup?)

Comment: @Fletch The documentation for `globalSetup` seems sparse and its not something I have tried. You will probably be better asking a new question as more people will see it than this comment on a year old question.